# Use rel attribute as anchor link

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor, rel

I'm wondering is it's possible to use a rel attribute as an anchor link. For instance, the html would read as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/portfolio" rel="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
<div id="portfolio">Content goes here></div>
```

When the link is clicked, instead of taking the user to the page, the current page will scroll to the content.

The idea is to have all or most site content on the home page and use the navigation at the top to link to the content down below. However, if javascript is not enabled, the user will be taken to the appropriate page.

Additionally, I'm using the code in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/5z3NH/1/) to activate smooth scrolling. I'd like to adapt it to suit the situation I described above.

Thanks in advance!

[Edit]

I've updated my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5z3NH/2/) to try a method Jukka suggested, that is, extracting the path from the href url and scrolling to a matching div down the page. It's not working yet, in that I end up linking to the URL, but maybe I can get a few more pointers.

Comment: 1st use `data-rel` instead of `rel` 2nd you must prevent default anchor behavior to be able to stay on the same page so your `href` attribute is useless in that scenario. I'm workin' on the Fiddle with smooth scrolling, take a look at [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Wqq6g/) and if you have any questions about it fell free to ask here in comments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this.

JS enabled

```
<nav class="script">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-rel="s1">Link 1</a>
    </li><li><a href="#" data-rel="s2">Link 2</a>
    </li><li><a href="#" data-rel="s3">Link 3</a>
    </li><li><a href="#" data-rel="s4">Link 4</a>
    </li><li><a href="#" data-rel="s5">Link 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<section id="s1">

</section>

<section id="s2">

</section>

...
```

---

```
$(function () {
  $('nav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('#'+ $(this).data('rel')).offset().top + 'px' }, 1000, 'easeOutSine');
  });
});
```

JS disabled

```
<noscript>
  <style>.script { display: none; }</style>

  <nav class="noscript">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Link 1</a>
      </li><li><a href="#sevices">Link 2</a>
      </li><li><a href="#portfolio">Link 3</a>
      </li><li><a href="#about">Link 4</a>
      </li><li><a href="#contact">Link 5</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</noscript>
```

Or universal solution like you tried in your fiddle

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com/#home">Link 1</a>
    </li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/#sevices">Link 2</a>
    </li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/#portfolio">Link 3</a>
    </li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/#about">Link 4</a>
    </li><li><a href="http://www.example.com/#contact">Link 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

```
$(function () {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $($(this).attr('href').replace('http://www.example.com/', ''));        
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top + 'px' }, 1000);        
  });
});
```

Your <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/5z3NH/4/)**</kbd> updated.

Comment: i think he would be happy with your answer :D

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't get at the heart of what I'm trying to do. The navigation will always be visible. What changes depending on javascript being enable is where the user is being taken, that being either down the page (if javascript is enabled) or to the url (if not enabled).

Comment: "The navigation will always be visible" No first navigation is visible to browsers which allow JS and second navigation to others without JS so you must include both navigations in your document just second navigation wrap inside `<noscript> </noscript>`.

Comment: I've updated your fiddle again, link must be with hash tag and target variable without. But on other hand why use full domain in links if meaning of navigation is to scroll or move page down?

Comment: Thanks so much! I think I've got it, though altered still just slightly from your final suggestion here. I want the urls to be the correct links, so no #'s. But a copy/paste of the code from you last comment did it. Final [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5z3NH/5/).

Answer (score 2):

No, that would not make sense and would not work. The `rel` attribute has a specific meaning, though it is largely ignored by browsers. It is not meant to affect and and it does not affect the destination address of a link.

If you just want to *move* to an element inside the page, you can simply use `<a href="http://www.example.com/portfolio#portfolio">Portfolio</a>`. No JavaScript needed.

If you instead wish to hide other content and *show* just one part of a page, in a “single-page application” manner, then you (in practice) need JavaScript in an essential way. To make the page still work without JavaScript (perhaps especially considering search engines), you can do much like in your question, but with a different attribute carrying the information, e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/portfolio" data-part="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
```

with an `onclick` event handler set to use the `data-part` attribute in a suitable way and to abort normal link processing.

In fact, you could probably dispense with such an extra attribute, with a suitable naming scheme. If your `id` attribute values match the last part of the URL, as in the example, your script could simply read the path part of the `href` attribute value – you that value as such, if you use normal relative URLs, as in `href=portfolio`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation. I believe the best option for me is the last one you described, that is, using the path part to link down the page and avoiding any additional attributes. Now to code it...

Comment: I've updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5z3NH/2/) attempting to extract the path name of the href url and use it to find a selector down the page, but I've obviously got something wrong because I'm just linking to the url.

Comment: About your Fiddle try this `$('a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); var url = $('#'+$(this).attr('href').replace('http://www.example.com/', ''));         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: url.offset().top }, 1000);        });`

Comment: @mdesdev Did that work for you? Do you have a working fiddle? I did add `e.preventDefault()` after the fact, so I'm not being taken to the URL anymore. However, I'm still not getting linked down the page. I know I'm getting the values #portfolio and #love in the target variable, but .offset doesn't seem to be using them appropriately.

Comment: Yes, I'll include the fiddle in my answer for couple of sec.